# Is it a bot when the user agent is "Java/1.6.0_32"?

Tags: user-agent, bots, spam

I log all visits to detect bots. Got sometimes visit with ip from another country and user agent like "Java/1.6.0_32". Is it probably a bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definately not one of the major browsers.  It's probably a screen-scraper - you could probably take it as a compliment that somebody finds the content provided by your site to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

"You could probably take it as a compliment that somebody finds the content provided by your site to be useful..."

You might be right, but I`m not 100% sure.

An unrecognized bot could be trying to steal you content, attempting to spam links or scanning for vulnerabilities...

I've checked [Botopedia.org](http://www.Botopedia.org) and found no reference for this user-agent. 
Might be fine, but it seems fishy to me.